# installed Ubuntu server in hp proliant ml350 g6 not booting up

Tags: server

Just now installed Ubuntu Server os in hp proliant ml350 g6, after the restart it's not booting up, showing

```
Attempting Boot from Hard Drive (C:)
```

Comment: Have you installed grub2?

Comment: Is this `wubi` install ?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your problem like [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482023/cannot-boot-into-new-install-of-ubuntu-14-server)

you have BIOS related issue where by default HP system show only  HP Smart Array Controller and will not show HDD . so , you have to set SATA settings in BIOS . for more info you can use given link .

Comment: When you find another question you think is the same as a question you are answering you should click flag under the question and choose `duplicate`, this really helps out the site and the OP will be notified about your flag. Not saying don't give an answer to the question, as you may be correct, just helps clean up a bit.

Comment: ok , thanks for information but scenario of previous post seems more specific  and this is common problem that happen with particular vendor product . it will be better if this question  will be separate  . if you think  to mark as duplicate then i can if possible .

Comment: The question will remain, it won't get removed, it will just be updated to include information from the dupe, also the OP will have a chance to tell us if it worked for them or not before answers are closed on the question, if OP rejects the dupe, question will stay open. Also it take 5 votes from 3000+ rep users to actually close a question, so you won't be causing it to close any time soon, the flag mostly informs the OP that a answer may already exist, it's not as bad as it sounds, but it is completely up to you if you want to flag it or not.